# how to echo head links in Zend controller which is set in bootstrap when layout is disabled

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework, view, controller

I am creating a document in one the pages in our website and I have to disable the layout.
All the CSS and JavaScript files are included via Bootstrap and I echo those links in layout.
So now I still need to add those links in controller of the page.

My code in bootstrap as follows:

```
$view->headLink()
    ->appendStylesheet('/css/bootstrap-cerulean.css')
    ->appendStylesheet('/css/bootstrap-responsive.css')
    ->appendStylesheet('/css/charisma-app.css');
```

I am trying to use this appended links in the related controller without having to type them one by one. Is There a way for me to pull this from Bootstrap and echo in controller action.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to share the stylesheets and javascript files and only switch between layouts?

Comment: i want to print them all if i can. I am using too many of those files and it will be time wasting to type every time i need such a thing.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what your use case is here? You should never echo anything from a controller action.

Comment: Create a second layout and switch between them.

Comment: @TimFountain i have to disable layout and my links echoed in the layout and the links are added to the application in the bootstrap. so when i disable layout, all the styles and scripts are gone. therefore i am looking for a way to include those headlinks in controller or in the view file so i do not have to type them everytime i need something like this.

Comment: @busypeoples how can i do what you suggest, could you post it if you know how to? i never did it and don't know at all.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html#zend.layout.quickstart.mvc

Comment: There is an example for switching between layouts.

Comment: it will do the job, if you post this as ananswer, i will vote it accepted. Thank You.

Comment: @Justin Try it out. If it works, post the answer to how you solved it. Maybe you might add some insights.

Comment: @busypeoples sure i am working on it right now, since i am new to this it is going a little slow for me sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

its not a good idea to do any view operations in controller action.
maybe think about using different layout in that action?